# Emacs auto-complete for installed library via quicklisp?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, cedet, quicklisp

I'm using Emacs 24.3 + SBCL + Slime + Quicklisp.
Emacs auto-complete works well in slime.

But, I usaully write lisp code in `.lisp` file where I can't load `cl library` because `.lisp` file is not REPL as you know.

**How can I do auto-complete without loading lisp file installed via `quicklisp`?**

Comment: Please don't add an answer to your question. Instead, if you solved this yourself, add it as an answer below. You will be able to accept that answer in a couple of days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by myself.

Just `(ql:quickload :wherever)` Then write a lisp code in `.lisp` file.
Now `semantic` will work. But, It depends on `semantic` configuration.
In my case, `.el` file didn't support auto-complete even if I loaded a library.